# webpack 4 pug loader image url not correct

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-4, pug-loader

according to the doc of [pug loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader#embedded-resources)

**Embedded resources**

Try to use require for all your embedded resources, to process them with webpack.

```
div
  img(src=require("./my/image.png"))
```

and it looks working with me the terminal emitted my image and no error

**But the url path not correct**

the code:

```
div.phone-container
    h1 
        a
            img(src=require('./../../assets/images/logo-sm.png'))
    .hamburger.hamburger--collapse
        .hamburger-box
            .hamburger-inner
```

Produce this weird url object :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since require function  return object - I don't know why -. I tried to extract the value using **.default** and It works
this is my code :

```
div.phone-container
    h1 
        a
            img(src=require('./../../assets/images/logo-sm.png').default)
    .hamburger.hamburger--collapse
        .hamburger-box
            .hamburger-inner
```

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. did you figure out way to ommit .default? and also it returns path \path\to\image.png instead of /path/to/image.png  (like in windows file system)

Comment: I've been experiencing this same issue, and I also would like to ommit the .default. @ErikKubica